# Выключение\включение подсветки монитора в windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7

Такая проблема, мне надо программно потушить подсветку монитора и потом включить её обратно, писал вот такой код:

```
SendMessage(Application.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 1);
```

Но почему-то не работает. Говорят, что это только на ХР прокатывает. А как на семерке такое сотворить?

Comment: Говорят, что на 98-й работало 0/-1. У кого-то на XP 0/-1 не работает, а работает 1/-1. На семёрке заработало только 2/-1. Что будет дальше?... 

Comment: читайте [документацию](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx).

    -1 (the display is powering on)
    1 (the display is going to low power)
    2 (the display is being shut off)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не совсем верно... надо:

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);//отключение
SendMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);//включение
```